# How to force background graphics printing on Chrome for Android?

Tags: chrome-for-android, printing

I am using Android 11. I could not get the version of Chrome I am using. I am using an OTG connector with a USB cable to connect my Android phone to my printer Ricoh Aficio SP C320DN. I'm also using the NokoPrint Android app.

In Chrome's desktop version, I can tell the browser to print background images through checking the "Background Graphics" option under more settings. I need to do the same on the mobile version. But I can not find the option when printing.

Does it exist somewhere? Or does not it exist at all?

P.S. I am developing an app using Oracle APEX and I need to enable users to print the web page themselves. Telling users to tick a checkbox or change a browser setting could be sufficient. It's been days since I am surfing the web, but all solutions do not work as expected.

Comment: Are you trying to print all images on the screen not just the foreground on part of the screen, could you not just take a screenshot and print it?

Comment: Yes, I need to print everything I see on the web page. I am developing an app using Oracle APEX and I need to enable users to print the web page themselves. I am searching for a JavaScript solution. But for now, Telling users to tick a checkbox could be sufficient. JavaScript solution will take time. It's been days I am surfing the web, but all solutions do not work as expected.

Comment: Note that Android Enthusiasts focus on Android end-users who are not necessarily developers. Comments focusing on the development part have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140817/discussion-on-question-by-eslam-how-force-background-graphics-printing-on-androi).

Comment: Related: [How do I print background colors on webpages in Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/249372/44325)