# How do I print background colors on webpages in Android?

Tags: printing

I'm trying to print a page from my work web app, and table cell colors are pretty critical. I know it's not available on Chrome or Android's native WebView app component (at least not in my work app).

How do I print background colors on webpages in Android? Does ANY Android browser allow this option?

Comment: Related for Chrome: [How to force background graphics printing on Chrome for Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/248390/44325)

Comment: Good question.  I don't know if it will help, but my first step would be to try Firefox for Android because it doesn't use WebView.